# What is a carriage return?

Tags: digital-logic, computers

I have this question where they ask you:

> Find a table of ASCII codes on the internet and give the ASCII code for each of the following in both denary and hexadecimal:
>
> 1. Uppercase R    Denary 82       hexadecimal 52
> 2. Lowercase w    Denary 119    hexadecimal 77
> 3. Carriage return

I answered the first two but not the last one please help.

Comment: Erm... just google ASCII carriage return? I did and the first page on Google took me here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/carriage-return-ascii-code-13.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Comment: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) ?

Comment: Carriage Return is often abbreviated to CR.

Comment: @RemcoVink Sadly, we can't mark cross-site duplicates...

Comment: Carriage return is shown about 9 seconds into this video: [Typing with a typewriter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKGiRm37ykI).

Answer (score 2):

If you do much programming you will probably have this committed to memory. Mostly because of CR (13), LF(10) (base 10) and the three different ways they are used to represent newline on three popular platforms (which leaves one way to get it wrong for all three). These are *control characters* and do not represent printable characters.

CR = Carriage Return

LF = Line Feed

'Denary' is an unusual way, in my experience, to refer to decimal (base 10) numbers. Perhaps the question is translated from another language or the author is being pedantic.